# Exchange Client That Supports Rules

Tags: applications, email

I set up rules in Outlook (which is synched to a Microsoft Exchange server) to automatically filter emails to specific folders, based on sender.

I have been able to sync the Android email client to my mail server, and the inbox contains all of the folders I had set up in Outlook.

My problem is that the Android email client offers no way to sync ALL email folders at once.  I have to sync each individually, which is not really feasible with over 20 folders.

Is there a better email client that will sync with Exchange AND allow synching of all folders under the inbox?

Thanks,
Seth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your rules on your server account to do that, so you don’t need the filtering rules on every client. Is very practical.

But don't remember now if K9 Mail client offer filtering/rule system

Also there is SEVEN Mail client that if i´m not wrong you can **create and modify server-side email rules**. With SEVEN you will get  PUSH mail notification for mail, exchange, imap, yahoo, etc...

Note1: Your can create the rules through OWA(Outlook Web Access). Rules created through OWA are Server side rules. Your Exchange server should have a OWA access point. Usually something like : https://owa.yourserverdomain.com

Comment: How do you configure that on the server?

Comment: @Seth I'd talk with whoever owns the Exchange server.  I know when I've created rules on my Exchange account they've been server rules automatically.

Comment: Create the rule through OWA(Outlook Web Access). Rules created through OWA are Server side rules. Your Exchange server should have a OWA access point. Usually something like : https://owa.yourserverdomain.com